# How do I reinstall Windows 10 while keeping my dual boot configuration?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

How do I reinstall Windows 10 while keeping my dual boot configuration?
I want to do a clean install of Windows 10. I have Ubuntu 16.04. I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: The latter is specific for Win 10.

Comment: @luchonacho That one is also specific to Ubuntu 14.04. This question is specific to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @karel That one is specific to Windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to the community, Isaiah!

Comment: Very important to know if UEFI or BIOS. IF Windows 10 was pre-installed by vendor it will be UEFI. But if you upgraded a Windows 7 to Windows 10 then it probably is BIOS. A few Windows 7 systems were UEFI. Either ways best to use Windows to shrink the main (c: drive) partition to make room and reboot immediately to let it run chkdsk. Also make sure Windows fast start up is off as that is hibernation and will not work to dual boot.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in this situation is that, if you install Windows 10, it will overwrite the MBR. <sup>Windows thinks it's the only OS in the world.</sup>

- Install Windows using Windows installation media.
- Boot using an Ubuntu Live CD. Choose the "Try Ubuntu" option.
- Open a terminal and type `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where `sdX` is your hard drive. The first hard drive is called `sda`, so if you only have one hard drive, replace `sdX` with `sda`.
- Press <kbd>↵</kbd>. After the command is executed run `sudo update-grub`
- After the command is executed, reboot your system and remove the live CD or USB when asked to in order to prevent booting into it.
- Voila! You will have grub restored with both OSes.

Comment: I suggested an edit. If you don't agree with some of the changes, improve the answer. If you don't agree at all, reject.

Comment: It is not showing a suggested edit

Comment: What? I'm sure I suggested it, the post even has the "Thanks for your edit!" indication for me. Check again; tell *the truth*.

Comment: I have never got an suggested edit to my answer. Does it show that in notifications. If so, it is not there, nor in feed, neither in my profile

Comment: Then you might have low rep count yet... I don't now exactly how many rep you need to review your own posts. Anyways, peers are there to review it for you. And yes, it shows up in the notifications.

Comment: This  doesn't seem to work with Unbuntu 18.04, /dev/sda is mounted to /cdrom and apparently this is the live media USB. mount command show no other sdx volumes mounted.