# How to reinstall Windows 10 while having dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

My Windows 10 wont boot, so I want to reinstall it. I already have a dual boot setup so I don't know if i can just reinstall Windows or I need to uninstall Ubuntu and than do it. What would be the best practice?

Comment: simply boot windows cd or usb and format the partition in which u installe windows and then install windows in the same drive.but now your grub will be gone so u will have to do boot repair ..there are already many links over askubuntu for that do it with gui.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: try the following [How do I reinstall Windows 10 while keeping my dual boot configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815807/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-10-while-keeping-my-dual-boot-configuration)